# Apache2 wildcard rewrite

Tags: server, apache2, php, wildcards

I have a php app on Apache2 that is supposed to treat subdomains on the code level.

My goal is to redirect any wildcard subdomain to the main domain's index.php. I do not use .htaccess.

I searched Stackoverflow and also googled for the solution, and could not find one. The virtual host looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin admin@website.com
      ServerName website.com
      ServerAlias *.website.com
      DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site_admin/public_html
      # Directory path where code exists
        <Directory /var/www/html/site_admin/public_html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/website.com-error.log
        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel error
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/website.com.log combined
        RewriteEngine On
        #If the domain (any domain) is not exactly website.com...
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^website\.com$ [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*) http://(.*).website.com [L,R=301,QSA]
        RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

When I access the main domain, I can see the website content. However, if I access sub.website.com, I get redirected to %28.%2A%29.website.com

Please advice

Thanks ahead

Igal

Answer (score 0):

If the PHP code is handling the subdomain rules by itself, there's no need to overcomplicate the Apache configuration. This is what I do for my PHP projects that support multiple addresses:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin your@email.addy
        DocumentRoot /var/www/project/public

        ServerName website.com
        ServerAlias *.website.com *.* *.*.*
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/project-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/project-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/project/public>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All

        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow From All
</Directory>
```

Note the multiple wildcards in the `ServerAlias` line. This will allow the server to respond to *all* traffic, even if the domain is not known by the application (which then allows for a PHP-based redirect to other capture process).

I generally keep rewrite rules out of the Apache configuration an instead put them in an `.htaccess` file, which I understand you do not currently use. Experience has shown that keeping rewrites out of the configuration file results in fewer "weird situations".

This is how I configure the `.htaccess` file that is used for projects with the Apache configuration found above:

```
Options +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php

Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; SameSite=None; Secure"

<filesMatch "\.(ico|css|js|pdf|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1209600, public"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|inc|log|sql|user|token)$">
        Order Allow,Deny
        Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/xml text/css text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml application/xhtml+xml application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rdf+xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf application/x-font-otf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/truetype font/opentype
</ifModule>
```

With this, Apache will pass all traffic to the PHP-based site and it's up to that code to perform redirects, access control, and URL translations

Comment: thank you, @matigo . I tried this config, but it does not work. if I access website.com i get a response. If I load subdomain.website.com I get 404

Comment: How does your PHP handle the domains? Is the 404 from Apache or the PHP code? I cannot debug your issue; I can only provide solutions that have worked for me over the years with the many servers and systems I am responsible for 

Comment: thank you, @matigo ! the subdomains are to be handled on the php level, and it looks like we are failing with 404 by the application, not apache. I will test your config on another server, with simple html files